# How to make something like iPhone Folders?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, transform, directory

I'm wanting to know if there's a way I can transform my view to look something like iPhone folders.  In other words, I want my view to split somewhere in the middle and reveal a view underneath it.  Is this possible?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Per the suggestion below, I *could* take a screenshot of my application by doing this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Not sure what to do with this, however.

**EDIT:2**
I've figured out how to add some shadows to my view, and here's what I've achieved (cropped to show relevant part):

[image]

**EDIT:3**

http://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders

Comment: ahhh well, I found you on cocoacontrols.com my good fellow ^^. open source FTW! =)

Comment: Indeed you did. Thanks for helping me get started on that in the first place. ;)

Comment: You can have a look at `OGActionChooser` ;) but it seems they have server problems currently :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the basic thought will be to take a picture of your current state and split it somewhere. Then animate both parts by setting a new frame. I don't know how to take a screenshot programmatically so I can't provide sample code…

EDIT: hey hey it's not looking great but it works ^^

```
// wouldn't be sharp on retina displays, instead use "withOptions" and set scale to 0.0
// UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *f = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect fstRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
CGRect sndRect = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 260); // was 0,200,320,280


CGImageRef fImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([f CGImage], fstRect);
UIImage *fCroppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:fImageRef];
CGImageRelease(fImageRef);

CGImageRef sImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([f CGImage], sndRect);
UIImage *sCroppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sImageRef];
CGImageRelease(sImageRef);


UIImageView *first = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:fstRect];
first.image = fCroppedImage;
//first.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
UIImageView *second = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:sndRect];
second.image = sCroppedImage;
//second.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;

UIView *blank = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
blank.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

[self.view addSubview:blank];
[self.view addSubview:first];
[self.view addSubview:second];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    second.center = CGPointMake(second.center.x, second.center.y+75);
}];
```

You can uncomment the two `.contentMode` lines and the quality will improve but in my case the subview has an offset of 10px or so (you can see it by setting a background color to both subviews)

//EDIT 2: ok found that bug. Had used the whole 320x480 screen, but had to cut off the status bar so it should be 320x460 and all is working great ;)

Comment: I think CoreGraphics or Cocos2d should work but maybe it's simpler to take to screenshots if you can specify a region to capture / or if you will use a UIImageView you can set the automatic resize to stay always in the top/bottom corner and then cut off the frame a little bit

Comment: Thanks for your hard work, it's looking good.  How would I return to the main view after doing this?

Comment: I think there are million ways xD but the easiest is to remove the 3 subviews (or more if its getting complex). For example if the user touches somewhere outside, I would handle it in touchesBegan:withEvent:

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    second.center = CGPointMake(second.center.x, second.center.y-75);
}]; and only after the animation period remove it from superview

Comment: comon it's not that hard to save the subview in a class variable ;) and by the way I would create a whole ViewController for this purpose

Comment: Already posted a question for this, but do you know how you'd change this to work with Retina?

Comment: that's the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() magic :D. scale 0.0 is used to take the resolution of the current screen (in fact retina if supported)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of taking a snapshot of the view, you could use a separate view for each row of icons. You'll have to do a bit more work with repositioning stuff, but the rows won't be static when the folder is open (in other words, they'll keep redrawing as necessary).

Comment: Dave, thanks for your comment!  I actually wasn't wanting the icons (should've clarified in my answer), but I just wanted to effect of splitting the view in half.

Answer (score 1):

I took [relikd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207616/relikd) code as a base and made it a bit more dynamic.

You can specify split position and direction when calling the function and I added a boarder to the split images.

```
#define splitAnimationTime 0.5
- (void)split:(SplitDirection)splitDirection
 atYPostition:(int)splitYPosition
withRevealedViewHeight:(int)revealedViewHeight{

    // wouldn't be sharp on retina displays, instead use "withOptions" and set scale to 0.0
    // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *f = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGRect fullScreenRect = [self getScreenFrameForCurrentOrientation];

    CGRect upperSplitRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,fullScreenRect.size.width, splitYPosition);
    CGRect lowerSplitRect = CGRectMake(0, splitYPosition, fullScreenRect.size.width, fullScreenRect.size.height-splitYPosition);


    CGImageRef upperImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([f CGImage], upperSplitRect);
    UIImage *upperCroppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:upperImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(upperImageRef);

    CGImageRef lowerImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([f CGImage], lowerSplitRect);
    UIImage *lowerCroppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:lowerImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(lowerImageRef);


    UIImageView *upperImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:upperSplitRect];
    upperImage.image = upperCroppedImage;
    //first.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

    UIView *upperBoarder = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, splitYPosition, fullScreenRect.size.width, 1)];
    upperBoarder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [upperImage addSubview:upperBoarder];


    UIImageView *lowerImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:lowerSplitRect];
    lowerImage.image = lowerCroppedImage;
    //second.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;

    UIView *lowerBoarder = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fullScreenRect.size.width, 1)];
    lowerBoarder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [lowerImage addSubview:lowerBoarder];

    int reveledViewYPosition = splitYPosition;

    if(splitDirection==SplitDirectionUp){
        reveledViewYPosition = splitYPosition - revealedViewHeight;
    }


    UIView *revealedView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, reveledViewYPosition, fullScreenRect.size.width, revealedViewHeight)];
    revealedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];


    [self.view addSubview:revealedView];
    [self.view addSubview:upperImage];
    [self.view addSubview:lowerImage];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:splitAnimationTime animations:^{
        if(splitDirection==SplitDirectionUp){
            upperImage.center = CGPointMake(upperImage.center.x, upperImage.center.y-revealedViewHeight);
        } else { //assume down
            lowerImage.center = CGPointMake(lowerImage.center.x, lowerImage.center.y+revealedViewHeight);
        }
    }];
}
```

This means I can call it like this:

```
[self split:SplitDirectionUp atYPostition:500 withRevealedViewHeight:200];
```

I used these conveniance functions in the updated split function:

```
- (CGRect)getScreenFrameForCurrentOrientation {
    return [self getScreenFrameForOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];
}

- (CGRect)getScreenFrameForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect fullScreenRect = screen.bounds;
    BOOL statusBarHidden = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden;

    //implicitly in Portrait orientation.
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        CGRect temp = CGRectZero;
        temp.size.width = fullScreenRect.size.height;
        temp.size.height = fullScreenRect.size.width;
        fullScreenRect = temp;
    }

    if(!statusBarHidden){
        CGFloat statusBarHeight = 20;
        fullScreenRect.size.height -= statusBarHeight;
    }

    return fullScreenRect;
}
```

and this enum:

```
typedef enum SplitDirection
{
    SplitDirectionDown,
    SplitDirectionUp
}SplitDirection;
```

Adding a return to normaal function and adding the arrow would be a great addition.

Comment: You might be interested in seeing a library I wrote a while ago that wraps all of this up. https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders

Comment: Heh yeah, sorry, I should have posted it. Here, have an upvote as consolation. :)