# How to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to adapt [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493837/how-to-make-something-like-iphone-folders/4493958#4493958) question to work with a retina display.  Here's how I figured out how to work with retina graphics for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
}
else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
}
```

However, when I use it the image looks really huge and doesn't scale down to fit the display.  Any ideas how I can tell it to resize the captured image to fit the boxes? (Please refer to the other question to understand what I mean).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've written this code to perform exactly the same thing described in the other post.
It works on any iOS device with at least iOS 3.1.

_launcherView is the view that need to be photographed

```
CGFloat scale = 1.0;
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {        
    CGFloat tmp = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    if (tmp > 1.5) {
        scale = 2.0;    
    }
} 

if(scale > 1.5) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_launcherView.frame.size, NO, scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_launcherView.frame.size);
}

[_launcherView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect upRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _launcherView.frame.size.width*scale, (diff - offset)*scale);
CGImageRef imageRefUp = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], upRect);
[self.screenshot1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenshot1.frame.size.width, diff - offset)];
[screenshot1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
UIImage * img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefUp];
[self.screenshot1 setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGImageRelease(imageRefUp);

CGRect downRect = CGRectMake(0, (diff - offset)*scale, _launcherView.frame.size.width*scale, (screenshot.size.height - diff + offset)*scale);
CGImageRef imageRefDown = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], downRect);
[self.screenshot2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenshot1.frame.size.height ,  screenshot2.frame.size.width, _launcherView.frame.size.height - screenshot1.frame.size.height)];
[screenshot2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
UIImage * img2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefDown];
[self.screenshot2 setBackgroundImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGImageRelease(imageRefDown);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have access to my machine ATM, but I'll try it as soon as I can and will accept it as answer.

Comment: If you have any problem please tell me, but i'm sure it will be easily adapted to fit your needs.

Comment: Works quite nicely, thanks!  I'm just wondering if this could be done with `UIImage`s instead of `UIButton`s.  I dislike the "click" effect that the buttons force.

Comment: Oh never mind, I can just use `screenshot1.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;` :)

Comment: Exactly, the button is useful to close the folder

Comment: What the @#$@# - this answer is not only incomplete but if you use this code it has nothing but compile problems - variables are not even defined!

Comment: If you look at the code is was written for iOS 3.1: four years ago... It is obvious that now has problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to this session, [iOS Memory Deep Dive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/416/), we had better use `ImageIO` to downscale images.

- Memory use is related to the dimensions of the images, not the file size.
- `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` always uses `SRGB` rendering-format, which use 4 bytes per pixel.
- A image have `load -> decode -> render` 3 phases.

For the following image, if you use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`
we only need 590KB to load a image, while we need
`2048 pixels x 1536 pixels x 4 bytes per pixel` = 10MB when decoding 
[image]

while `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, introduced in iOS 10, will automatically pick the best graphic format in iOS12. It means, you will save 75% of memory by replacing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` if you don't need SRGB.

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

func resize() =

let imgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil)
if let imageSource = imgSource {
    let options: [NSString: Any] = [
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 100,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true
    ]
    let scaledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as CFDictionary)
}
```

I took some notes [here](https://suelan.github.io/2020/05/03/iOS-images-in-memory/) for this session.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (UIImage *)getNewimage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Comment: it corrupts the image.