# Take a screenshot of UIScrollView, starting at contentOffset point?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I looked at this code here, which lets you take a screenshot of either the top visible portion of a UIScrollView or of the whole UIScrollView:

[Getting a screenshot of a UIScrollView, including offscreen parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts)

What I want is to take a screenshot of just the portion from contentOffset onwards, as the UIScrollView can be quite long and thus it would take a while to take a screenshot of it. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you mentioned basically resize the scroll view to match the size of its content, and therefore the entire content will be rendered without a scroll and then captured.

If you want to apply the same solution, you can resize the scroll view to match the size of the visible content + the size of remaining content til the end.

So try to replace those lines:

```
_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
_scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                    _scrollView.contentSize.width, 
                    _scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

With:

```
//_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero; // Don't change the offset
_scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                    _scrollView.contentSize.width, 
                    _scrollView.contentSize.height - _scrollView.contentOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had asked similar question before [Taking screenshot of Part of Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109413/taking-screenshot-of-part-of-screen)

You can take screenshot of what the user is seeing in terms of 320 x 480 but you cannot take screenshot of a portion of the screen. X and Y coordinates have absolutely no effect on where the screenshot starts/stops.