# Segue animation similar to opening an app in iOS 7: viewcontroller frame is not resizable

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am willing to create a segue animation similar to opening an app in iOS 7. Now I consider this approach: [Non-segue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486506/animation-similar-to-opening-app-in-ios7), but encountered an issue: if being implemented in custom segue, the code cannot resize viewcontroller's frame, which is principal part of the animation. As I can see, it applies viewcontroller's position, but cannot change it's size. Am I correct, that property viewcontroller.view.frame cannot be animated and has to remain constant and equal to size of the device's screen? I already implemented something similar with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`, but its a bit weird, so, I am looking for better solution. Below I paste the code I use for the segue.

```
#import "ZoomSegue.h"
#import "MiniMapViewController.h"
#import "InteractiveMapViewController.h"

@implementation ZoomSegue

- (void)perform {
    InteractiveMapViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    MiniMapViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
    destinationViewController.view.hidden = NO;


    //Just to check, lets make view really small. Position it to the center we get from the segue.
    destinationViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(_originatingPoint.x, _originatingPoint.y, 60.0f, 60.0f);

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];


    float animationDuration = 1.5f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration/2.0f animations:^{
        destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];



    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{


        //Just to check, lets make view very big. It does not work, although, the view goes to the upper left corner, so position works, but not the size
        CGRect x  = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 9590.0f, 91366.0f);

        destinationViewController.view.frame = x;
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're correct, but a better way to do it anyway is to use a snapshot view. This code puts a small snapshot in the center of the screen then expands it to full size,

```
- (void)perform {
    UIView *sourceView = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
    UIView *destinationView = [((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    destinationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 5);
    destinationView.center = CGPointMake(sourceView.center.x, sourceView.center.y);
    [sourceView addSubview:destinationView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         destinationView.frame = sourceView.frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];

}
```

**After Edit:**

Here is a translation of the code in the link you provided that converts that animation into a segue,

```
-(void)perform {
    CGFloat duration = .25;
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIView *bg = [source.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    bg.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
    UIViewController *dest = self.destinationViewController;
    UIView *icon = [dest.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
    icon.frame = self.iconFrame;
    icon.alpha = 0.0f;
    [source.view addSubview:bg];
    [source.view addSubview:icon];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        icon.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration*2 animations:^{ 
        icon.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds;
        bg.frame = [self zoomedRect];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [source presentViewController:dest animated:NO completion:nil];
        [bg removeFromSuperview];
        [icon removeFromSuperview];
    }];

}



- (CGRect)zoomedRect {
    float screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width;
    float screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height;

    float size = screenWidth / self.iconFrame.size.width;
    float x = screenWidth/2 - (CGRectGetMidX(self.iconFrame) * size);
    float y = screenHeight/2 - (CGRectGetMidY(self.iconFrame) * size);

    return CGRectMake(x, y, screenWidth * size, screenHeight * size);
}
```

I have a CGRect property, iconFrame in the .h file of the segue. I performed the segue from a tap gesture recognizer that was attached to the icon that will be expanded. You need to pass the frame of that icon to the segue, which I do in the source view controller's prepareForSegue method,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(SpringboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    segue.iconFrame = sender.view.frame;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had this kind of idea, but to create some kind of "screenshots" and use as UIImageView. I will try your idea now.

Comment: It works almost as it should be. Now I need sourceView also to zoom in just a bit, but without affecting it's children. Is it possible to make these transformations relative to some static point?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy, I don't think that's possible, but could you explain a little more what you want.

Comment: You can see it here on the animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486506/animation-similar-to-opening-app-in-ios7

Comment: @RichardTopchiy, not sure what you mean about not affecting its children. It looks to me like that animation is done by adding a small snapshot of the new view overtop where the icon is, then expanding and moving a snapshot of the source view (which has the other snapshot as a subview) in such a way that the small snapshot ends up centered and full screen.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but check the background: its another view and its being independently transformed to a bigger scale.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy, I've updated my answer with code that converts the code in the link you gave to a segue.

Comment: Thank you! Please also add something as `[icon removeFromSuperview]; [bg removeFromSuperview];`, after this line: `[source presentViewController:dest animated:NO completion:nil];`, cause if these snapshots are not being removed from their's super they appear after unwinding a segue.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy, Thanks for that. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've translated the same code in SWIFT.

```
class CustomOpenSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
   var iconFrame = CGRect()

   override func perform(){

    var sourceViewController: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
    var bg:UIView = sourceViewController.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    bg.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var destinationViewController: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    var icon:UIView = destinationViewController.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    icon.frame = self.iconFrame
    icon.alpha = 0.0

    sourceViewController.view.addSubview(icon)



    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        icon.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil )

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            () -> Void in
            icon.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            bg.frame = self.zoomedRect

    }) { (finished) -> Void in

        sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)
        icon.removeFromSuperview()
        bg.removeFromSuperview()


        }
    }


    var zoomedRect:CGRect{
        var screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        var screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        var size = screenWidth / self.iconFrame.size.width
        var x = screenWidth / 2 - CGRectGetMidX(self.iconFrame) * size
        var y = screenHeight / 2 - CGRectGetMidY(self.iconFrame) * size

        return CGRectMake(x, y, screenWidth * size, screenHeight * size)
    }
}
```

And this is how you call it:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue is CustomOpenSegue{
    let customOpenSegue = segue as CustomOpenSegue
    customOpenSegue.iconFrame = self.mapButtonFrame!
    }
}
```