# how to do a "app launch like" fade - zoom ios 7 transition?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewanimationtransition

I need to achieve the IOS7 app launch transition, in which the the detail view appears with fade effect according to the rectangle frame of the button that fired this view, as described in the image below:

[image]

So I have a main ViewController with six buttons, I want to make transition to the details viewControllers with fade and zoom effect, and starting the animation depending of the button frame.

I found [RZTransitions](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZTransitions), amazing collection of custom transitions, it does exactly what I want but for uicollectionView, I tried but can't get working to do the same for a viewController.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe using [UIView animation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Basic_iOS_7_Animation_using_Core_Animation) you can achieve what you are looking for...

Comment: Yes I agree but I need how to. Thanks any way.

Comment: It will be grateful so, waiting for.. I'll send you an email from mine.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922583/segue-animation-similar-to-opening-an-app-in-ios-7-viewcontroller-frame-is-not),,, might help

Comment: This might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486506/animation-similar-to-opening-app-in-ios7